# Right/left aligning with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I cannot wrap my head around `fancyhdr` and a two-paged document. This is what I have now:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{\nameOfBook{}} }

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{ \nouppercase{Kapitel \thechapter: \leftmark}} }
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{ \nouppercase{\rightmark}} }

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
  \fancyhf{} % remove everything
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

What I would like to have is that the header text on the left page is left aligned (with respect to the page number, giving a small room), and similar for the right page. I don't know if it's a good solution (visually) or if I should aim on page numbers at the bottom while keeping the texts at the top. To be able to decide I need to be able to align the text first, but I fail to do that.

**Question**: How do I left/right align the header texts while respecting a small area reserved for the page numbers?

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess, what you are doing ...

Comment: What should be these texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all the material in the left or right header as needed, with the page number in a box of fixed width using the `\makebox` macro and the other text immediately after or before corresponding to even or odd pages.  The syntax for `\makebox` is

```
\makebox[width][pos]{Text}
```

with `pos` one of `l`, `r` or `c`, for left, right or centered material within the box.  It is good to specify the `width` in units that depend on the font, such as `em`.  Below I have used `1.5em`, which gives you space for a three digit page number.

Left page:

[image: Sample left page]

Right page:

[image: Sample right page]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{The Book Title}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thepage}\textbf{\nouppercase{Kapitel \thechapter: \leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}\makebox[1.5em][r]{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
  \fancyhf{} % remove everything
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{21}
\chapter{Some chapter title}
\section{A section of some sort}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Beware of spaces added in your macros - for example, your orginal code added a space before `Kapitel`, which I have removed above.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works in a standalone tex-file for testing, but somehow `\rightmark` becomes empty when I put the code into my `.sty`-file. Using my old code, `\rightmark` is not empty, but when changing into your code it becomes empty. Odd, so I will have to dive down into the class-file and see what's causing the emptiness.

Comment: Strange, as that part of the code has not changed.  Are you sure you do not have a typing/copying error.